# Stop components from loading halfway

Tags: angular

I've built an app using angular 7, which is quiet intensive on the browser and has a lot of heavy components. WheneverIi navigate from a semi loaded component to another component, it takes quiet some time. My question: can I, somehow, stop the initialization of the currently loading component and start the initialization for the next component?

I know, lazy loading and pre-loading could be one of the possible solutions for my problem, but it's not that effective.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. What is this heavy initialization you're doing? Does it consist of asynchronous operations, like HTTP requests? Is it data processing? You can interrupt asynchronous operations. However, JavaScript is single-threaded and cannot be interrupted. In that case you may need to research worker threads.

Comment: It consists of multiple async calls and data processings. In addition it draws a canvas using SVGs hence the lag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For asynchronous operations, I would make sure to use Observables and unsubscribe from them to interrupt their work.
See https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables#cancellation

For data processing, I suggest you look into worker threads (or web workers). This is a JavaScript feature, and there are many articles and questions here already covering web workers and integrating them with Angular.
Since web workers run in separate threads, the main thread (the one running Angular) can cancel tasks submitted to web workers.

Edit: For canvas, there's also an experimental API, `OffscreenCanvas`, which allows you to perform draw operations inside web workers.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas

If you choose not to use web workers or `OffscreenCanvas`, however, I think all you can do is optimize the way you use canvas. If you make clever use of the `window.requestAnimationFrame()`, executing small batches of operations every frame, I think you can construct a drawing process that will have less impact on the main thread, and could be interrupted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas